# how to use ContentObserver..?

Tags: android, contentobserver

I'm very new to this stuff and could't find an appropriate answer. I did something by myself, i don't know to what extent i'm rite. and its not working.

```
package com.aqui.observer;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.provider.ContactsContract;

    public class ObserverActivity extends Activity {
        private MyObserver observer;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            observer = new MyObserver(new Handler());
            getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(observer);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
         getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, true, observer);
    }
}
```

and this is my observer.

```
package com.aqui.observer;

import android.database.ContentObserver;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyObserver extends ContentObserver{

    public MyObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(null);
    }
@Override
public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
    super.onChange(selfChange);
    Log.e("CHANGEsTrappedSuccessfully", "YEAH..YEAh");
}
}
```

thank you in advance.

Comment: http://www.devdaily.com/java/jwarehouse/android/core/java/android/database/ContentObserver.java.shtml

Comment: @nik.. that looks very complex and in 2.1 its very simple i know. thanks any ways.

Comment: @ntc What is the use case that you are trying to do? When you say "could't find an appropriate answer.", appropriate answer to what question and what is exactly that is not working?

Comment: The "super(null);" looks suspicious.

Comment: I just answered it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11980856/726863)