# differentiate inbox and sentsms from all sms

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am working on an ANdroid application.In my app I have to list all the conversations and i did that part.Each conversation is containing all sms to that number. So i have to differtiate inbox and sentsms from all sms.I know about the following api's can use to find inbox and sent.

```
content://sms/inbox
content://sms/sent
```

But i don't want to use this.I listed all sms by using the api

```
content://sms/
```

I tested with the columnindex's type,address but it always gives the same result for inbox and outbox.And my sample code is

```
Uri SMS_INBOX = Uri.parse("content://sms");
        c = getContentResolver().query(SMS_INBOX, null, "thread_id" + " = "
                        + "3", null,
                        "date" + " ASC");
        if(c.moveToFirst()){
            count.add(c.getCount());
            for(int j=0;j<c.getCount();j++){
                System.out.println(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")).toString());
                System.out.println("new   person=="+c.getColumnIndex("person")+"type=="+c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("type"));
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        c.close();
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use ContentObserver here to track sent and received message,

Override `onChange()` method of `ContentObserver` and get the sms type and work accordingly. Psuedo code can be as below.

```
Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Uri
                             .parse("content://sms"), null, null, null, null);

String type = cursor.getColumnIndex("type");
if(cursor.getString(type).equalsIgnoreCase("1")){
    // sms received
 }
 else if(cursor.getString(type).equalsIgnoreCase("2")){
    //sms sent
 }
```

Registering `ContentObserver` for SMS,

```
ContentResolver observer = this.getContentResolver();
observer.registerContentObserver(Uri.parse("content://sms"), 
                               true, new MySMSObserver(new Handler(),this));
```

Where `MySMSObserver` will be your class extending `ContentObserver` with Constructor having argument as Handler and Context,

```
public MySMSObserver(Handler handler, Context context) {
        super(handler);
        this.context = context;
}
```

Comment: @Lalit..Thanks for the quick reply

Comment: @lalit .I di differenciation by cursor.getString(type).equalsIgnoreCase. Then why could I use contentobserver???

Comment: because ContentObserver will observe your inbox changes. Its `onChange()` will be called everytime when a sms is received or sent.

Comment: I think the DataType of 'type' needs to be `int` and not `String`